Conditional statement in locals
I've removed the initial question to simplify.
Is there a way to print the value of tolist(local.port_mappings) to see what the issue is?
Thanks to @DharaniDharGolladasari - just use an output!
locals = {
     host_ports = [for port in local.all_ports: {"containerPort": tonumber(port), "hostPort": tonumber(port), "protocol": "tcp"}]
 
     port_mappings = var.ecs_task_definition_network_mode == "host" ? [for port in local.all_ports: {"containerPort": tonumber(port), "hostPort": tonumber(port), "protocol": "tcp"}] : [for port in local.all_ports: {"containerPort": tonumber(port), "protocol": "tcp"}]
}

Outputs:
Changes to Outputs:
  + host_ports                  = [
      + {
          + containerPort = 8080
          + protocol      = "tcp"
        },
    ]
  + port_mappings               = [
      + {
          + containerPort = "8080"
          + hostPort      = "8080"
          + protocol      = "tcp"
        },
    ]

So it looks like the conditional statement is removing the tonumber() and treating the number as a string.
Is this intentional? Anything I can do to make it respect the tonumber?

I'm not sure how to print what the output is which is the original question.
It works when I don't have it in a conditional statement, it does not work within the conditional statement. So the conditional statement is causing the issue, I just don't know why

Have you tried using an output value to print the tolist(local.port_mappings).

@DharaniDharGolladasari Thank you! For some reason hadn't thought of that. I've updated the question with the findings.

looks like I find out what happened here - terraform handles the type conversion properly, but local.port_mappings have additional tomap function inside, and because of this, terraform convert all variables to the same type (string in our case), as described in the documentation.
You can check this by using terraform console:
$ terraform console
> local.port_mappings
[
  tomap({
    "containerPort" = "8080"
    "hostPort" = "8080"
    "protocol" = "tcp"
  }),
]

I can't say why this happens and couldn't find a way for disable this behaviour, but if you move this [for ...] to the upper layer, all start to works as expected:
locals {
     all_ports = ["8080"]

     host_ports = [for port in local.all_ports: {"containerPort": tonumber(port), "hostPort": tonumber(port), "protocol": "tcp"}]

     container_ports = [for port in local.all_ports: {"containerPort": tonumber(port), "protocol": "tcp"}]

     port_mappings = var.ecs_task_definition_network_mode == "host" ? local.host_ports : local.container_ports

}

$ terraform console
> local.port_mappings
[
  {
    "containerPort" = 8080
    "hostPort" = 8080
    "protocol" = "tcp"
  },
]

Look at the second output - we don't have additional tomap() function, and I believe because of this we have a numbers instead of strings.

Seems like Terraform is not handling the type conversion properly. Can you try converting the port_mappings to numbers explicitly and use them in conditional statements.
Then the example script will looks like something below:
locals = {

 #Explicitly converting the ports from String to numbers
 port_numbers = [for port in local.all_ports: tonumber(port)]

 host_ports = [for port in local.port_numbers: {"containerPort": port, "hostPort": port, "protocol": "tcp"}]

 port_mappings = var.ecs_task_definition_network_mode == "host" ? [for port in local.port_numbers: {"containerPort": port, "hostPort": port, "protocol": "tcp"}] : [for port in local.port_numbers: {"containerPort": port, "protocol": "tcp"}] 
 
    }

This might help to ease the conversion task to Terraform. Refer this official tonumber document for more information.

Unfortunately, I get the same error, the ports are treated as strings
